# Django - two sections from the same model

Tags: django

I have 'sites' section in my admin page. Here is part of my models.py:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
        subcategory = ChainedForeignKey(
        'Subcategory',
        chained_field='category',
        chained_model_field='category',
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    description = models.TextField()
    keywords = MyTextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, editable=False)
    url = models.URLField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I would like to add another Sites section in my admin which will only show inactive sites (is_active = False). Is it possible? (I mean:

```
Sites - first section (list of all sites)
Inactive sites (number of inactive sites) - second section (only inactive sites)
```

)

Here is my admin class:

```
class SiteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('is_active', 'name', 'description', 'keywords', 'date')
    fields = ('name', 'url', 'category', 'subcategory', 'description',
              'keywords', 'date', 'is_active')
    readonly_fields = ('date',)
    list_editable = ('is_active',)
    list_display_links = ('name',)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by registering an admin page for a [proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models), and overriding the [`get_queryset` method of the registered `ModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset).

You can only register an object once in the admin site, so the proxy model acts as a new model to be registered separately. Since it's only a proxy model, its presence only impacts Python code and won't create a new model in the database.

The `get_queryset` command is how `ModelAdmin` gets the model instances to display, so by overriding it we can add whatever filtering we want.

In your case you would add something like this to the `admin.py` file in your app.

```
class InactiveSite(Site):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name_plural = 'Inactive sites'

class InactiveSiteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return self.model.objects.filter(is_active=False)

admin.site.register(InactiveSite, InactiveSiteAdmin)
```